# Substring + Concat on Virtual Fields in CakePHP - possible?

Tags: php, cakephp, substr, concatenation

This seems like a simple question, but I can't get it to work.  I've created a virtual field that combines a name and address:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'name_address' => 'CONCAT(Venue.name, " - ", Venue.address)'
);
```

Is there a way to use `SUBSTR` on this?  (PHP or MYSQL is fine - whichever is best/works).

I've tried this (to no avail):

```
'name_address' => 'SUBSTR(CONCAT(Venue.name, " - ", Venue.address),0,50)'
```

I've also tried SUBSTR on the individual fields within the CONCAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely no problem. Your only error is, that you thought of the SUBSTRING-function in MySQL working like the one in PHP where the count starts at zero.
But since this isn't PHP you have to start your counting from `1` and all will work fine.

Just use your virtualField like this and it should work just like you want:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'name_address' => 'SUBSTRING(CONCAT(Venue.name, " - ", Venue.address),1,50)'
);
```

Also, have a read on the SUBSTRING-function [in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)